# Python - Most efficient way to select kth value from (expanded) dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, percentile

I'm doing large scale analysis of several hundred GBs of data, however it is streamed and I want the most efficient solution to compute mode and percentiles. How I'm currently doing it is rounding numbers (there are ping times in decimals, such as 55.4381 or 33.97818) to the nearest tenths place, and recording the number of these occurrences in a dictionary. For example:

```
a = {48.8: 5, 42.3: 24, 56.1: 3}
```

This I've found is the best way that is accurate enough for my needs, while still being memory efficient. The optimal way I've thought of is to use an ordered dictionary, compute the number of keys in the dictionary, and grab the kth key in sorted order. So, getting the 50th percentile of the above data would be `a[(32*0.5)-1] -> a[15] -> 42.3`, if that makes sense. Essentially grabbing the kth element of a list, if said list were to be, in this case, `[42.3, 42.3, ..., 42.3, 48.8, 48.8, 48.8, 48.8, 48.8, 56.1, 56.1, 56.1]`, but without needing to allocate the memory for that list.

So, I'd like to know if anyone has any ideas on the most efficient way to do this. I'm using Python 3.5.2 currently. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What you show here is that you are using *strings* for the key values, rather than just the float numbers themselves. If you are truly doing this, you will be vulnerable to "asciibetical" sorting problems. Particularly, the problem of "1, 10, 100, 101, 102, ..., 109, 11, 110, ..."

Comment: My mistake, I've edited it to reflect that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: It sounds like this program would spend over 99% of its time gathering data, then a tiny bit of time at the end analyzing it and generating output. No? So there is little point in looking for an efficient solution in that part.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do? At this granularity, if response times are somewhere between 0 and 15 minutes, you would have 15 * 60 * 10 = 9000 entries in your dictionary, which should be easily managed as a list of pairs, or whatever. If you actually want to expand it back into a sequence of numbers, for example to feed to the `statistics` module or something, you might be better off using `itertools` to concatenate some generators.

Comment: I'd like to calculate percentiles based off the dict, like the example given in the post. It spends a rather large amount of time computing because it does do a good bit of analysis other than just this. It resolves IPs to locations, to ASNs, other things. I'm mainly looking for a solution that is easy on compute and memory. And @AustinHastings for the 9000 entries, it does that on a per day basis, so 9000 entries per day across ~4 years of data, = 13,140,000 entries total, split across ~1200 dicts. If I were to expand it, I'd be looking at several hundred million or more.

Comment: This might be true if you're doing daily reporting. But the response times are not date-dependent. A time of 0.5s on Tuesday will be 0.5. A time of 0.5s on Wednesday will be 0.5. Unless you take steps to prevent it, the times will always fall into the same 9000 buckets. If you can sort the input by datestamp, then you can detect the end of day, do whatever daily computations you like, and purge that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# We want this percentile.
pct = 0.25

# Data.
a = {48.8: 5, 42.3: 24, 56.1: 3}

# Find that percentile in this data.
def pctile(a, pct):
    # Convert to list of tuples, sort
    LofT = list(a.items())
    LofT.sort()

    # Sum of counts.
    ct = sum(a.values())

    # Index corresponding to percentile. Don't subtract 1; e.g. ct = 100,
    # 25th pctile, 25% are below, we want index 25, below which there are
    # 25 values. But do round to nearest integer.
    pcti = int(ct * pct + 0.5)

    # Traverse sorted list until this index is reached.
    for v, c in LofT:
        pcti -= c
        if pcti < 0:
            return v

    # Still here? Then pct was >= 1, just return the maximum value.
    return LofT[-1][0]
```

Time complexity is O(*n* log *n*) where *n* = `len(a)`, due to the sort step.